# Need to make third party objects serializable without writing wrapper

Tags: java, serialization

I have third party platform jars of which APIs need to be tested using webservices.
These APIs take custom objects which are non serializable. 
Say for example some of the APIs are like this.

```
doSomething(CustomId someId, DBLoaderType type, DBFilter filter, boolean exclude) returns java.util.List<SomeNavigationSystem>
```

But these `CustomId`, `DBLoaderType`, `DBFilter`, `SomeNavigationSystem` are not serializable objects.

Is there a way that I need not write any extra classes for all these classes  (there is a lot of such classes) to serialize? If I write one wrapper or equivalent DTO for each business class then this will be very unscalable.

Comment: Do these objects have internal state that is not "public"?

Comment: Do you have to use standard Java Serialization? There are libraries such as XStream and GSon which allow you to serialise any object.

Comment: @Jeremy, These objects may have internal non public attributes.

Comment: Do they have constructors that can accept enough public attributes to "reconstitute" objects to a working/usable state?

Comment: @Olaf : most of the constructors are default but we have setter methods to set the states.

Comment: @Java_Master: In this case I'm with @Peter Lawrey: do your own serialization, consider using libraries like XStream.

Comment: Well with XStream we need to keep the jar in the client side. If tomorrow this jar changes we need to change this jar on the client side also which is not permissible according to one requirement. So using XStream is not possible. If that restriction is removed XStream solves lot of other problems also. But using XStream is not possible as it requires jar on the client side. Any alternative suggestions?

Comment: Or do we have any way to convert data/Object to xml or any other format without using jar on client side?

Comment: In general, you can't convert arbitrary objects to a byte stream and then back in a way that they will work afterwards. Consider cases like Thread or FileOutputStream - there is no way to transfer them sensibly to the other side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using [XSteram](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) it fixed my issues.

Answer (score 2):

please have a look at the Google gson lib under http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/.

I am not sure if I fully understood your problem, but if you want to serialize objects that do not implement java.io.Serializable you should consider json or one of its implementations. Assuming that your objects are serializable from their 'nature', gson can serializable them into a string. Your web service schema may look ugly later, but it could work. You will end up in sending strings.

Comment: This approach works great so long as the types map back to rather simple types when you repopulate objects with the saved data. For example, you might have a JSON string, but that might map to a more complex class which represents a string, but isn't a java.lang.String.